# Plot conditional logistic regression with spline term

Tags: plot, conditional-statements, logistic-regression, spline, logistics

Hi friends in stackoverflow,

I am trying to plot the **conditional logistic regression with spline** using R (similar graph below but using conditional logistic regression). I haven't found good way to do this. Does anyone have ideas? Thanks a lot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csnfh.png)